# How could rpc cross lan network?

Tags: rpc

RPC server need an ip address to bind to, which the client could access the remote procedure with the ip address as an argument.

But what if the server is in a company's LAN, how could a remote client(not in the LAN) access a rpc server in the LAN?

Answer (score 0):

**You'll need to forward the ports that your use in your router to your the ip-address of your server. Also you need to open the ports on your server.**

Your server is then accessible from the IP-address that you will find at: [What Is My Ip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/)
Also a link for forwarding ports: [portforward](http://portforward.com/)